# Joining same column names causes na.fill to fail in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to use the Scala API for Spark, and want to join a number of tables together, then fill in the null values as zeroes.

```
val left = Seq(("bob", 6), ("alice", 10), ("charlie", 4)).toDF("name", "count")
val right = Seq(("alice", 100),("bob", 23)).toDF("name","count")
val df = left.join(right, Seq("name"), "left_outer")
df.na.fill(0)
df.orderBy(left("count")).show(3)
```

However, I get

```
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Reference 'count' is ambiguous, could be: count#6619, count#6629.;
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.resolve(LogicalPlan.scala:264)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.resolveQuoted(LogicalPlan.scala:168)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.resolve(Dataset.scala:218)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.col(Dataset.scala:921)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameNaFunctions.org$apache$spark$sql$DataFrameNaFunctions$$fillCol(DataFrameNaFunctions.scala:411)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameNaFunctions$$anonfun$2.apply(DataFrameNaFunctions.scala:162)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameNaFunctions$$anonfun$2.apply(DataFrameNaFunctions.scala:159)
  at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
  at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
  at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
  at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.foreach(ArrayOps.scala:186)
  at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:234)
  at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.map(ArrayOps.scala:186)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameNaFunctions.fill(DataFrameNaFunctions.scala:159)
```

I've tried a number of different `fill(...)` functions (`fill(0, Seq("right.count"))`, `fill(0, Seq("count"))`, etc.) and all give the same failure. Commenting out the `fill(...)` line makes it complete fine, however there are nulls where I want zeroes.

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of duplicates in the column names:

```
scala> val df = left.join(right.withColumnRenamed("count", "count2"), Seq("name"), "left_outer")
                    .na.fill(0)
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [name: string, count: int ... 1 more field]

scala> df.show
+-------+-----+------+
|   name|count|count2|
+-------+-----+------+
|    bob|    6|    23|
|  alice|   10|   100|
|charlie|    4|     0|
+-------+-----+------+


scala> df.orderBy(left("count")).show(3)
+-------+-----+------+
|   name|count|count2|
+-------+-----+------+
|charlie|    4|     0|
|    bob|    6|    23|
|  alice|   10|   100|
+-------+-----+------+
```